# How do I grab the objects from php Twitter API

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, twitter

So I can get the tweets using Twitter Oauth I can echo the tweets using foreach. But I want to grab the data from the php and bring them to another page.

Index.php contains the json array of tweets.

Then in page2.php I have the code below to display specific objects using $.ajax get from index.php

```
   $.ajax({
     dataType: "html",
     url: 'index.php',
     success:function(data){
    //$('#tweets').html(data['text']);
    $.each(data, function () {
    list += '<p>'+ this.text +'</p>';
});
    $('#tweets').html(list);
}
```

});

But when I  try to specify the a particular object to grab like the text I get no results. Do use

```
 data['text']
```

or

```
data->text
```

Answer (score 0):

From observing your current code, you're using the JQuery GET method to send the data to the PHP file.

I am 99% sure that the following should work:

```
$_GET['list'];
```

Comment: I think I posted it wrong. the index page contains the twitter api in php and json. But I want page to grab the json objects and use jquery to display the data..

Comment: In that case, I am not too sure then. I'd have to give it a go to see the results.